# Ubuntu 12.04 for Asus EeePC 1225C

Tags: asus

In some market, Asus EeePC 1225C comes with Ubuntu preloaded. See Asus site - http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1225C/

In India it comes with DOS, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it and it has issues with display and track-pad. Any idea which Ubuntu image is used and can be made available to install on 1225C?

Comment: What kind of issues are you having?

Comment: display 1024x768. Using this solution I now get 1366x768 - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11976680&postcount=97

Comment: track-pad is too sensitive, Ogg, mp4 videos jerks.

Comment: You'll need to contact Asus and ask. I suspect they may have added a third party driver or two.

Comment: ok. will ask...

Comment: Do you still want to have an answer? otherwise, you can close the question

Comment: @Matcha: I own a Acer D270 which also has `intel gma 3600` and I can't play mp4 videos in it. The reason I believe is the support for gma600 in linux. I asked a [similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/154011/32063).

Comment: From:ASUS TSD    
To:Matcha    
Date:2012-07-06 01:49:08   
    
Dear Valued Customer,   
    
Thank you for contacting ASUS Customer Service.      

Hi, for your issue, I am sorry that we don't have drivers for Ubuntu. So I suggest you donwload it by visiting the website of Ubuntu for a try.   
Sincerely sorry for the inconvenience!    
    
Wish you good luck! I do appreciate for your feedback!    
If you continue to experience issues in the future, please do not hesitate to contact us.   
    
Best Regards,

Comment: In this case, how does ASUS manage to sell devices with Ubuntu preinstalled on this hardware?

Answer (score 2):

I asked asus support about this Ubuntu and they said it was specially modified, but they don't want to share their distro.

Comment: Shame on you, ASUS.